# Why does my app return 500 when sign up as new user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm new in RoR, It's my first app (making it by Rails tutorial https://www.railstutorial.org/book), I deployed it to production but when signing-up as new user - app crashing. 
Here is logs after executing command: heroku logs --tail

```
2019-01-25T15:09:25.394996+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users" host=cryptic-chamber-73265.herokuapp.com request_id=17171a6c-7f95-4614-b020-f61d91772e10 fwd="194.44.208.54" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=513ms status=500 bytes=1891 protocol=https
2019-01-25T15:33:30.048373+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-77ce2dba2f1cc8f497ef3f72f3b022a7cf57165d3eb5e73f8f178986029772b5.js" host=cryptic-chamber-73265.herokuapp.com request_id=448fc543-2d68-4044-8a14-97b01d475d86 fwd="194.44.208.54" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=54395 protocol=https
2019-01-25T15:33:29.909373+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=cryptic-chamber-73265.herokuapp.com request_id=eee2b892-da3c-4f63-87b4-e15e115d4a8a fwd="194.44.208.54" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=3131 protocol=https
2019-01-25T15:33:30.298489+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/kitten-44dde42a7808d66c6f314c6587e2c0faabb03d8a3c2c47e4d07e09c08e3c1c6b.jpg" host=cryptic-chamber-73265.herokuapp.com request_id=08f07a54-7653-45a0-a663-9410b9e75f39 fwd="194.44.208.54" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=10ms status=200 bytes=141536 protocol=https
2019-01-25T15:33:30.799387+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=cryptic-chamber-73265.herokuapp.com request_id=16018457-8605-4b2a-b043-9dbecc73cbf8 fwd="194.44.208.54" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=207 protocol=https
2019-01-25T15:33:33.367482+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:33:33.367375 #4]  INFO -- : [fe40d8ae-ce58-4d6e-b719-affa82010b13] Started GET "/signup" for 194.44.208.54 at 2019-01-25 15:33:33 +0000
2019-01-25T15:33:33.370085+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:33:33.370016 #4]  INFO -- : [fe40d8ae-ce58-4d6e-b719-affa82010b13] Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
2019-01-25T15:33:33.371608+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:33:33.371545 #4]  INFO -- : [fe40d8ae-ce58-4d6e-b719-affa82010b13]   Rendering users/new.html.erb within layouts/application
2019-01-25T15:33:33.374658+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:33:33.374581 #4]  INFO -- : [fe40d8ae-ce58-4d6e-b719-affa82010b13]   Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
2019-01-25T15:33:33.377248+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:33:33.377183 #4]  INFO -- : [fe40d8ae-ce58-4d6e-b719-affa82010b13]   Rendered users/_form.html.erb (3.2ms)
2019-01-25T15:33:33.378258+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:33:33.378193 #4]  INFO -- : [fe40d8ae-ce58-4d6e-b719-affa82010b13]   Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (4.4ms)
2019-01-25T15:33:33.379090+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:33:33.379030 #4]  INFO -- : [fe40d8ae-ce58-4d6e-b719-affa82010b13]   Rendered layouts/_rails_default.html.erb (0.6ms)
2019-01-25T15:33:33.380495+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:33:33.380434 #4]  INFO -- : [fe40d8ae-ce58-4d6e-b719-affa82010b13]   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
2019-01-25T15:33:33.381137+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:33:33.381049 #4]  INFO -- : [fe40d8ae-ce58-4d6e-b719-affa82010b13]   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.4ms)
2019-01-25T15:33:33.381437+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:33:33.381376 #4]  INFO -- : [fe40d8ae-ce58-4d6e-b719-affa82010b13]   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
2019-01-25T15:33:33.381750+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:33:33.381636 #4]  INFO -- : [fe40d8ae-ce58-4d6e-b719-affa82010b13] Completed 200 OK in 11ms (Views: 10.4ms)
2019-01-25T15:33:58.266697+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-01-25T15:33:58.266569 #4] DEBUG -- : [01d9b789-9c5f-4be1-a800-d44454168829]   User Create (8.0ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("name", "email", "created_at", "updated_at", "password_digest", "activation_digest") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "new aaa"], ["email", "pllak@gmail.com"], ["created_at", "2019-01-25 15:33:58.177889"], ["updated_at", "2019-01-25 15:33:58.177889"], ["password_digest", "$2a$10$WvK5Aw5HqcCFvktNpRJ62.9Oj8UMAr.q7hpx2iCoa9lLAt2/BnWMu"], ["activation_digest", "$2a$10$pyQr.p6mt1P2Lu4WXcHNcuC4DFUFxk2s7W7Qze0gZ6dz0yjcFhHbu"]]
2019-01-25T15:33:58.269371+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-01-25T15:33:58.269260 #4] DEBUG -- : [01d9b789-9c5f-4be1-a800-d44454168829]    (2.2ms)  COMMIT
2019-01-25T15:33:58.271131+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:33:58.271060 #4]  INFO -- : [01d9b789-9c5f-4be1-a800-d44454168829]   Rendering user_mailer/account_activation.html.erb within layouts/mailer
2019-01-25T15:33:58.271619+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:33:58.271526 #4]  INFO -- : [01d9b789-9c5f-4be1-a800-d44454168829]   Rendered user_mailer/account_activation.html.erb within layouts/mailer (0.3ms)
2019-01-25T15:33:58.271980+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:33:58.271908 #4]  INFO -- : [01d9b789-9c5f-4be1-a800-d44454168829]   Rendering user_mailer/account_activation.text.erb within layouts/mailer
2019-01-25T15:33:58.272299+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:33:58.272208 #4]  INFO -- : [01d9b789-9c5f-4be1-a800-d44454168829]   Rendered user_mailer/account_activation.text.erb within layouts/mailer (0.2ms)
2019-01-25T15:33:58.274730+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-01-25T15:33:58.274661 #4] DEBUG -- : [01d9b789-9c5f-4be1-a800-d44454168829] UserMailer#account_activation: processed outbound mail in 4.9ms
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358418+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:33:58.358268 #4]  INFO -- : [01d9b789-9c5f-4be1-a800-d44454168829] Sent mail to pllak@gmail.com (83.4ms)
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358468+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-01-25T15:33:58.358389 #4] DEBUG -- : [01d9b789-9c5f-4be1-a800-d44454168829] Date: Fri, 25 Jan 2019 15:33:58 +0000
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358470+00:00 app[web.1]: From: from@example.com
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358471+00:00 app[web.1]: To: pllak@gmail.com
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358473+00:00 app[web.1]: Message-ID: <5c4b2c66436b9_42adfd7a0b7fc2285f@7ec49837-e025-4e55-8763-3a59b9d7d59e.mail>
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358474+00:00 app[web.1]: Subject: Account activation
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358475+00:00 app[web.1]: Mime-Version: 1.0
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358477+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358478+00:00 app[web.1]: boundary="--==_mimepart_5c4b2c66429cd_42adfd7a0b7fc2275d";
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358480+00:00 app[web.1]: charset=UTF-8
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358481+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358482+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358483+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358484+00:00 app[web.1]: ----==_mimepart_5c4b2c66429cd_42adfd7a0b7fc2275d
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358485+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Type: text/plain;
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358486+00:00 app[web.1]: charset=UTF-8
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358488+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358489+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358490+00:00 app[web.1]: Hi new aaa,
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358491+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358492+00:00 app[web.1]: Welcome to the Sample App! Click on the link below to activate your account:
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358493+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358494+00:00 app[web.1]: https://cryptic-chamber-73265.herokuapp.com/account_activations/56t0efaFPNeJYZwZoCwpzQ/edit?email=pllak%40gmail.com
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358495+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358496+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358498+00:00 app[web.1]: ----==_mimepart_5c4b2c66429cd_42adfd7a0b7fc2275d
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358499+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Type: text/html;
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358500+00:00 app[web.1]: charset=UTF-8
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358501+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358502+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358503+00:00 app[web.1]: <!DOCTYPE html>
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358504+00:00 app[web.1]: <html>
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358505+00:00 app[web.1]: <head>
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358506+00:00 app[web.1]: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358507+00:00 app[web.1]: <style>
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358508+00:00 app[web.1]: /* Email styles need to be inline */
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358510+00:00 app[web.1]: </style>
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358511+00:00 app[web.1]: </head>
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358512+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358513+00:00 app[web.1]: <body>
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358514+00:00 app[web.1]: <h1>Sample App</h1>
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358515+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358517+00:00 app[web.1]: <p>Hi new aaa,</p>
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358518+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358519+00:00 app[web.1]: <p>
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358520+00:00 app[web.1]: Welcome to the Sample App! Click on the link below to activate your account:
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358521+00:00 app[web.1]: </p>
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358522+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358523+00:00 app[web.1]: <a href="https://cryptic-chamber-73265.herokuapp.com/account_activations/56t0efaFPNeJYZwZoCwpzQ/edit?email=pllak%40gmail.com">Activate</a>
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358524+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358525+00:00 app[web.1]: </body>
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358526+00:00 app[web.1]: </html>
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358528+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358529+00:00 app[web.1]: ----==_mimepart_5c4b2c66429cd_42adfd7a0b7fc2275d--
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358530+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-01-25T15:33:58.358736+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:33:58.358668 #4]  INFO -- : [01d9b789-9c5f-4be1-a800-d44454168829] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 350ms (ActiveRecord: 69.7ms)
2019-01-25T15:33:58.359463+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-01-25T15:33:58.359399 #4] FATAL -- : [01d9b789-9c5f-4be1-a800-d44454168829]
2019-01-25T15:33:58.359529+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-01-25T15:33:58.359470 #4] FATAL -- : [01d9b789-9c5f-4be1-a800-d44454168829] Net::SMTPFatalError (550 Unauthenticated senders not allowed
2019-01-25T15:33:58.359530+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2019-01-25T15:33:58.359591+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-01-25T15:33:58.359534 #4] FATAL -- : [01d9b789-9c5f-4be1-a800-d44454168829]
2019-01-25T15:33:58.359682+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-01-25T15:33:58.359611 #4] FATAL -- : [01d9b789-9c5f-4be1-a800-d44454168829] app/models/user.rb:51:in `send_activation_email'
2019-01-25T15:33:58.359685+00:00 app[web.1]: [01d9b789-9c5f-4be1-a800-d44454168829] app/controllers/users_controller.rb:22:in `create'
2019-01-25T15:37:27.274140+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:37:27.274050 #4]  INFO -- : [0aef2ecc-8a27-4adb-9288-168ae5b73f84] Started GET "/users" for 194.44.208.54 at 2019-01-25 15:37:27 +0000
2019-01-25T15:37:27.274746+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:37:27.274674 #4]  INFO -- : [0aef2ecc-8a27-4adb-9288-168ae5b73f84] Processing by UsersController#index as HTML
2019-01-25T15:37:27.275548+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:37:27.275496 #4]  INFO -- : [0aef2ecc-8a27-4adb-9288-168ae5b73f84] Redirected to https://cryptic-chamber-73265.herokuapp.com/login
2019-01-25T15:37:27.275748+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:37:27.275689 #4]  INFO -- : [0aef2ecc-8a27-4adb-9288-168ae5b73f84] Filter chain halted as :logged_in_user rendered or redirected
2019-01-25T15:37:27.275929+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:37:27.275848 #4]  INFO -- : [0aef2ecc-8a27-4adb-9288-168ae5b73f84] Completed 302 Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2019-01-25T15:37:27.431348+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:37:27.431236 #4]  INFO -- : [4ad04d5c-4f49-43be-9c4f-c4f5ba3dd2b8] Started GET "/login" for 194.44.208.54 at 2019-01-25 15:37:27 +0000
2019-01-25T15:37:27.432226+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:37:27.432150 #4]  INFO -- : [4ad04d5c-4f49-43be-9c4f-c4f5ba3dd2b8] Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
2019-01-25T15:37:27.436236+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:37:27.436166 #4]  INFO -- : [4ad04d5c-4f49-43be-9c4f-c4f5ba3dd2b8]   Rendering sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application
2019-01-25T15:37:27.439290+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:37:27.439220 #4]  INFO -- : [4ad04d5c-4f49-43be-9c4f-c4f5ba3dd2b8]   Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.9ms)
2019-01-25T15:37:27.440226+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:37:27.440159 #4]  INFO -- : [4ad04d5c-4f49-43be-9c4f-c4f5ba3dd2b8]   Rendered layouts/_rails_default.html.erb (0.6ms)
2019-01-25T15:37:27.440497+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:37:27.440442 #4]  INFO -- : [4ad04d5c-4f49-43be-9c4f-c4f5ba3dd2b8]   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
2019-01-25T15:37:27.441067+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:37:27.441011 #4]  INFO -- : [4ad04d5c-4f49-43be-9c4f-c4f5ba3dd2b8]   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.4ms)
2019-01-25T15:37:27.441595+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:37:27.441539 #4]  INFO -- : [4ad04d5c-4f49-43be-9c4f-c4f5ba3dd2b8]   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
2019-01-25T15:37:27.441975+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:37:27.441917 #4]  INFO -- : [4ad04d5c-4f49-43be-9c4f-c4f5ba3dd2b8] Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 8.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2019-01-25T15:37:27.444990+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/login" host=cryptic-chamber-73265.herokuapp.com request_id=4ad04d5c-4f49-43be-9c4f-c4f5ba3dd2b8 fwd="194.44.208.54" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=14ms status=200 bytes=3700 protocol=https
2019-01-25T15:38:06.064627+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/signup" host=cryptic-chamber-73265.herokuapp.com request_id=6b902b9a-f0d4-4efd-97e5-f4c45dd66c41 fwd="194.44.208.54" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=25ms status=200 bytes=3570 protocol=https
2019-01-25T15:38:06.040151+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:38:06.040043 #4]  INFO -- : [6b902b9a-f0d4-4efd-97e5-f4c45dd66c41] Started GET "/signup" for 194.44.208.54 at 2019-01-25 15:38:06 +0000
2019-01-25T15:38:06.041397+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:38:06.041332 #4]  INFO -- : [6b902b9a-f0d4-4efd-97e5-f4c45dd66c41] Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
2019-01-25T15:38:06.043183+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:38:06.043118 #4]  INFO -- : [6b902b9a-f0d4-4efd-97e5-f4c45dd66c41]   Rendering users/new.html.erb within layouts/application
2019-01-25T15:38:06.044801+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:38:06.044740 #4]  INFO -- : [6b902b9a-f0d4-4efd-97e5-f4c45dd66c41]   Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
2019-01-25T15:38:06.053992+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:38:06.053540 #4]  INFO -- : [6b902b9a-f0d4-4efd-97e5-f4c45dd66c41]   Rendered users/_form.html.erb (10.0ms)
2019-01-25T15:38:06.054146+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:38:06.054081 #4]  INFO -- : [6b902b9a-f0d4-4efd-97e5-f4c45dd66c41]   Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (10.8ms)
2019-01-25T15:38:06.059171+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:38:06.059098 #4]  INFO -- : [6b902b9a-f0d4-4efd-97e5-f4c45dd66c41]   Rendered layouts/_rails_default.html.erb (0.9ms)
2019-01-25T15:38:06.059475+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:38:06.059418 #4]  INFO -- : [6b902b9a-f0d4-4efd-97e5-f4c45dd66c41]   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
2019-01-25T15:38:06.060412+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:38:06.060262 #4]  INFO -- : [6b902b9a-f0d4-4efd-97e5-f4c45dd66c41]   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.6ms)
2019-01-25T15:38:06.060856+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:38:06.060799 #4]  INFO -- : [6b902b9a-f0d4-4efd-97e5-f4c45dd66c41]   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
2019-01-25T15:38:06.061233+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:38:06.061170 #4]  INFO -- : [6b902b9a-f0d4-4efd-97e5-f4c45dd66c41] Completed 200 OK in 20ms (Views: 18.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2019-01-25T15:38:20.644152+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:38:20.644055 #4]  INFO -- : [445886de-ce39-4a78-a693-3120e5f4a0d1] Started POST "/users" for 194.44.208.54 at 2019-01-25 15:38:20 +0000
2019-01-25T15:38:20.644973+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:38:20.644904 #4]  INFO -- : [445886de-ce39-4a78-a693-3120e5f4a0d1] Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
2019-01-25T15:38:20.645099+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:38:20.645034 #4]  INFO -- : [445886de-ce39-4a78-a693-3120e5f4a0d1]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Cp5BGCCQBsSIiSpjeas/WkKc44Gz0J+XCvgAgFa1gz3FNdJ5p2lpx27O+/zzMA5sHuFHnwxIkmaxeisPy+Bj3g==", "user"=>{"name"=>"fgfbfbf", "email"=>"asdfe@fdf.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Create my account"}
2019-01-25T15:38:20.731698+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-01-25T15:38:20.731581 #4] DEBUG -- : [445886de-ce39-4a78-a693-3120e5f4a0d1]    (1.2ms)  BEGIN
2019-01-25T15:38:20.734049+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-01-25T15:38:20.733946 #4] DEBUG -- : [445886de-ce39-4a78-a693-3120e5f4a0d1]   User Exists (1.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER($1) LIMIT $2  [["email", "asdfe@fdf.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-01-25T15:38:20.810621+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-01-25T15:38:20.810507 #4] DEBUG -- : [445886de-ce39-4a78-a693-3120e5f4a0d1]   User Create (1.6ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("name", "email", "created_at", "updated_at", "password_digest", "activation_digest") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "fgfbfbf"], ["email", "asdfe@fdf.com"], ["created_at", "2019-01-25 15:38:20.734539"], ["updated_at", "2019-01-25 15:38:20.734539"], ["password_digest", "$2a$10$KntymuRtkB709eSZBg2SqOEaXJD4ACaWef62FxKgkRTouW4dgmj0W"], ["activation_digest", "$2a$10$dmt.iB7GsDD8csUUFWRB3OYrmD/brabHBHOgohRonzAEa2xIWtvQG"]]
2019-01-25T15:38:20.813395+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-01-25T15:38:20.813325 #4] DEBUG -- : [445886de-ce39-4a78-a693-3120e5f4a0d1]    (2.5ms)  COMMIT
2019-01-25T15:38:20.814594+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:38:20.814505 #4]  INFO -- : [445886de-ce39-4a78-a693-3120e5f4a0d1]   Rendering user_mailer/account_activation.html.erb within layouts/mailer
2019-01-25T15:38:20.815000+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:38:20.814934 #4]  INFO -- : [445886de-ce39-4a78-a693-3120e5f4a0d1]   Rendered user_mailer/account_activation.html.erb within layouts/mailer (0.3ms)
2019-01-25T15:38:20.815316+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:38:20.815263 #4]  INFO -- : [445886de-ce39-4a78-a693-3120e5f4a0d1]   Rendering user_mailer/account_activation.text.erb within layouts/mailer
2019-01-25T15:38:20.815592+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:38:20.815541 #4]  INFO -- : [445886de-ce39-4a78-a693-3120e5f4a0d1]   Rendered user_mailer/account_activation.text.erb within layouts/mailer (0.2ms)
2019-01-25T15:38:20.817819+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-01-25T15:38:20.817764 #4] DEBUG -- : [445886de-ce39-4a78-a693-3120e5f4a0d1] UserMailer#account_activation: processed outbound mail in 4.0ms
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879454+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:38:20.879347 #4]  INFO -- : [445886de-ce39-4a78-a693-3120e5f4a0d1] Sent mail to asdfe@fdf.com (61.4ms)
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879580+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-01-25T15:38:20.879508 #4] DEBUG -- : [445886de-ce39-4a78-a693-3120e5f4a0d1] Date: Fri, 25 Jan 2019 15:38:20 +0000
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879584+00:00 app[web.1]: From: from@example.com
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879586+00:00 app[web.1]: To: asdfe@fdf.com
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879588+00:00 app[web.1]: Message-ID: <5c4b2d6cc7fc0_42adfd7a0ba4023076@7ec49837-e025-4e55-8763-3a59b9d7d59e.mail>
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879589+00:00 app[web.1]: Subject: Account activation
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879591+00:00 app[web.1]: Mime-Version: 1.0
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879593+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879595+00:00 app[web.1]: boundary="--==_mimepart_5c4b2d6cc740b_42adfd7a0ba402294d";
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879596+00:00 app[web.1]: charset=UTF-8
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879598+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879600+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879601+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879603+00:00 app[web.1]: ----==_mimepart_5c4b2d6cc740b_42adfd7a0ba402294d
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879604+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Type: text/plain;
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879606+00:00 app[web.1]: charset=UTF-8
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879607+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879609+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879610+00:00 app[web.1]: Hi fgfbfbf,
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879612+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879614+00:00 app[web.1]: Welcome to the Sample App! Click on the link below to activate your account:

2019-01-25T15:38:20.879650+00:00 app[web.1]: <!DOCTYPE html>
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879652+00:00 app[web.1]: <html>
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879653+00:00 app[web.1]: <head>
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879655+00:00 app[web.1]: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879656+00:00 app[web.1]: <style>
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879658+00:00 app[web.1]: /* Email styles need to be inline */
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879660+00:00 app[web.1]: </style>
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879661+00:00 app[web.1]: </head>
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879662+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879664+00:00 app[web.1]: <body>
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879666+00:00 app[web.1]: <h1>Sample App</h1>
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879667+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879669+00:00 app[web.1]: <p>Hi fgfbfbf,</p>
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879671+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879672+00:00 app[web.1]: <p>
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879674+00:00 app[web.1]: Welcome to the Sample App! Click on the link below to activate your account:
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879676+00:00 app[web.1]: </p>
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879677+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879679+00:00 app[web.1]: <a href="https://cryptic-chamber-73265.herokuapp.com/account_activations/5u7oWKY2L-q-L5BaJ6U5_w/edit?email=asdfe%40fdf.com">Activate</a>
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879681+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879682+00:00 app[web.1]: </body>
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879684+00:00 app[web.1]: </html>
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879686+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879687+00:00 app[web.1]: ----==_mimepart_5c4b2d6cc740b_42adfd7a0ba402294d--
2019-01-25T15:38:20.879689+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-01-25T15:38:20.880055+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-25T15:38:20.879977 #4]  INFO -- : [445886de-ce39-4a78-a693-3120e5f4a0d1] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 235ms (ActiveRecord: 6.6ms)
2019-01-25T15:38:20.881163+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-01-25T15:38:20.881065 #4] FATAL -- : [445886de-ce39-4a78-a693-3120e5f4a0d1]
2019-01-25T15:38:20.881265+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-01-25T15:38:20.881195 #4] FATAL -- : [445886de-ce39-4a78-a693-3120e5f4a0d1] Net::SMTPFatalError (550 Unauthenticated senders not allowed
2019-01-25T15:38:20.881268+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2019-01-25T15:38:20.881365+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-01-25T15:38:20.881308 #4] FATAL -- : [445886de-ce39-4a78-a693-3120e5f4a0d1]
2019-01-25T15:38:20.881500+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-01-25T15:38:20.881401 #4] FATAL -- : [445886de-ce39-4a78-a693-3120e5f4a0d1] app/models/user.rb:51:in `send_activation_email'
2019-01-25T15:38:20.881504+00:00 app[web.1]: [445886de-ce39-4a78-a693-3120e5f4a0d1] app/controllers/users_controller.rb:22:in `create'
2019-01-25T15:38:20.883841+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users" host=cryptic-chamber-73265.herokuapp.com request_id=445886de-ce39-4a78-a693-3120e5f4a0d1 fwd="194.44.208.54" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=240ms status=500 bytes=1891 protocol=https
https://cryptic-chamber-73265.herokuapp.com
```

This is my production config file:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Ensures that a master key has been made available in either ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]
  # or in config/master.key. This key is used to decrypt credentials (and other encrypted files).
  # config.require_master_key = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options)
  config.active_storage.service = :local

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  # config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
  # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment)
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "sample_app_#{Rails.env}"

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  host = 'cryptic-chamber-73265.herokuapp.com'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port           => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => Rails.application.credentials.SENDGRID_USERNAME,
    :password       => Rails.application.credentials.SENDGRID_PASSWORD,
    :domain         => 'heroku.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

On my local machine everything works fine, but when I deployed to production - I'm receiving this crash "
We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information."

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your environment variables SENDGRID_USERNAME and SENDGRID_PASSWORD on your config/credentials.yml.enc file

This command is going to use your config/master.key to open your config/credentials.yml.enc so you can add your variables

```
rails credentials:edit
```

Add your variables and save the changes

```
SENDGRID_USERNAME: 'user'
SENDGRID_PASSWORD: 'pass'
```

Push your changes to heroku and try again.

**Note:** You can check is this is working with rails console on your local environment

```
rails console -e production

Rails.application.credentials.SENDGRID_USERNAME
```

Comment: After executing command "rails console -e production" and then in irb> Rails.application.credentials.SENDGRID_USERNAME -> value nil

Comment: I checkouted changes in my config/credentials.yml.enc and after executing command "rails console -e production" and then in irb> Rails.application.credentials.SENDGRID_USERNAME file and I have "nil" value (and for password the same). Should I copy these value from my heroku app?

Comment: remember those variables are case sensitive SENDGRID is not the same as sendgrid. Let me see the contents of config/credentials.yml.enc (without the real password)

Comment: I tried different combinations (upper case and lower case) and it still return nill. Here is the value of my credentials.yml.enc: zJB/QoYB8CytnizJEDClBXYWy/zSLoRJDpAg51R0KMjs54E7+O376zRAaVCU1mkUOyUkj3uvm7EujKuSVWPDfhWOOJ0LLVBRAUj6vlVcLIsz8UXzmeUF15ycV/Cf0aq/i2I8BJiw56CCXnyhbNIt9uy8BWbl+VB7MN1fd7FQGkL7iPus0GPlDCtGNTGmNyzksGYFczQgtW/eykkKE7rRakPzB53hXlrAgJojPgRgy6yODdfRFGsUgDjZMCnxB3swBQWqpNYPyVZAgWaPr9QaKdkirJbeINz/p4WKvgdxru4jtnnCL2NAMaOzQmcyFZczx5EOsNpBWwaFB6PYsSAVd5I5QQYqIm9iAMX2v9GYYQjVT3lT7YPWabqlf2V+B8DxPMTUdx2cRIgDo7iHntJ84t9rpUtfnqyoXyqU--OGgxppCCUcog9JrP--KwvgCvgkEE1k288ET4lAXQ==

Comment: Also after executing commands $ heroku config:get SENDGRID_USERNAME
                                                   $ heroku config:get SENDGRID_PASSWORD I can see it values

Comment: No, I mean the contents when you run rails credentials:edit, do you see something like this: SENDGRID_USERNAME: 'user'

Comment: To use Rails.application.credentials.SENDGRIP_USERNAME, when you run rails credentials:edit, you have to see inside your credentials.yml.enc the variable on the form SENDGRIP_USERNAME: 'valuehere'

Comment: After command $ EDITOR="mate --wait" bin/rails credentials:edit I received "New credentials encrypted and saved."

Comment: And here is the all message after executing command $EDITOR="nano" bin/rails credentials:edit -> https://prnt.sc/menk01

Comment: That picture is showing you the nano editor, put your variable on it in the form SENDGRIP_USERNAME: 'myuser' and save the changes(Ctrl + x, yes)

Comment: Do these steps? -> execute command "heroku config:get SENDGRID_USERNAME" -> copy its value("xxx") -> SENDGRIP_USERNAME: 'xxx' -> and paste this all to my credentials.yml.enc and then push to heroku?

Comment: No, you run the rails credentials:edit on you local pc, edit the credentials.yml.enc, save it, make a commit of the changes and push to heroku